# modifying rake db commands to use a different mysql engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am trying to setup a rails 3 application on mysql cluster. I am noticing that whenever I create tables with rake db:create or rake db:migrate, the tables are created with engine=InnoDb. Since I am using MySQL cluster, this is problematic. I have to create tables with engine=NDB. I was wondering what would be the best way to modify the rake db:create and rake db:migrate logic so that it creates tables with engine=NDB instead.

Thanks/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for an existing table, you should create a migration to alter table, inside it you need to execute alter table command :

```
class Change < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute('ALTER TABLE some_tables ENGINE = NDB')
  end

  def self.down
    execute('ALTER TABLE some_tables ENGINE = innodb')
  end
end
```

But for new schema, you can use :options option on create_table method :

```
create_table :some_tables, :option => 'ENGINE = NDB' do |t|
 ...
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.3/migrations.html#creating-a-table

Comment: Possibly rails's bug, but above execute('alter table...') doesn't change schema.rb properly, so I assume engine goes back to innodb (default) when you run rake db:schema:load.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. schema.rb shouldn't contain such information as it should be database-independent. I need to use sql-style dump (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you )